# Can I have both cron and simple trigger for quartz?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz-core, quartz

I want to run Quartz Job using both triggers: cron and simple. Or are other ways to specify multiple intervals for one job?

`<trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>Trigger_Name</name>
        <job-name>Job_Name</job-name>
        <job-group>DEFAULT</job-group>
        <!-- It will run every day at 00hr-->
        <cron-expression>0 0 0 * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
      <simple>
        <name>Trigger_Name</name>
        <group>DEFAULT</group>
        <job-name>Job_Name</job-name>
        <job-group>DEFAULT</job-group>
        <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
        <repeat-interval>10000</repeat-interval>
      </simple>
    </trigger>`

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple triggers for one job. You can also schedule your Jobs with the `Scheduler` programmatically.